# Are basic system administrator utilities such as useradd or adduser standardized?

Tags: administration, standard

Are basic system administrator utilities such as useradd or adduser standardized? If so, where can I find the specs? (POSIX doesn't seem to encompass those, but I might need to take a better look).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you know that you can use `-b` and `-d` flag for useradd?

Comment: I mean, I'm not quite sure what you're asking and what you're trying to achieve. What you're saying could be done with rather simple Bash script, but I don't really understand the question. Could you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these utilities are not standardized. A quick look through the `useradd(8)` manual on RHEL6 versus OpenBSD reveals that while there are similarities, various flags differ in purpose. For a broader view, http://bhami.com/rosetta.html lists under "managing users" a variety of different commands, depending on the particular flavour of unix.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `man useradd` and `man adduser` to read manuals of each of these utilities to get an idea about how they work. AFAIK, there is no "standard reference sheet" for these utilities.

You might also take a look at [shadow page](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/), where you can find sources.

Comment: That all looks very debian-specific. I don't want debian specific. I want Unix-specific.

Comment: @PSkocik `man` is **very** Unix-specific. Source code may be "debian-specific", but as I said, there's no standard for them, so you won't get much better than that.